# profitabilité ou rentabilité ?

Tags: sens

Are these two words synonyms, or do they have different shades of meaning? I thought that only **rentabilité** existed, but I have just come across **profitabilité**

From these definitions they look quite similar:

1. La **profitabilité** est le rapport entre le profit et la production. Le
   taux de profitabilité donc rapporte le résultat net comptable au
   chiffre d'affaires hors taxes (RNC/CAHT).
2. La **rentabilité** représente le rapport entre les revenus d'une société
   et les sommes qu'elle a mobilisées pour les obtenir.

Merci!  :-)

Comment: in accounting, profitable in English is rentable in French. Profitabilité is also profitability, yes. But in French, it also means: return on investment and cost effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

The OECD recommands to use *rentabilité* instead of *profitabilité* in French as the former one is an Anglicism (according to [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indice_de_profitabilit%C3%A9), citing *Glossaire anglais-français de l'économie, Organisation de coopération et de développement économiques, 2006*).

However, there are still 2 entries in Wikipedia, one for [indice de profitabilité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indice_de_profitabilit%C3%A9) and another for [rentabilité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rentabilit%C3%A9). Each of them has a distinct formal mathematical definition and *profitabilité* is related to [profitability index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profitability_index) and *rentabilité* is related to [return on capital employed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_capital_employed) or [return on equity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_equity)

Comment: both rentabilité and profitabilité are profitability in English. And the French profitabilité is this says INSERM: Définition
La profitabilité est le rapport entre le profit et la production. Le taux de profitabilité donc rapporte le résultat net comptable au chiffre d'affaires hors taxes (RNC/CAHT).